# Calculating connection rate (ms) (latency)

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm trying to calculate the latency of the connected client (server->client) I want to do this during my ping loop (where it tests to see if the client is still connected) here is how I am ping it (trying to send data, if it fails client has been disconnected).

```
        while (information.connectionEst)
        {
            try
            {


                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("");

                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                killConnection();
                thread.Abort();
            }

        }
```

I assume I will need to calculate the time it took to send the packet of data. But i'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be appeciated.

Comment: A simpl-ish solution (assuming you're implementing both client and server), is to have the server send the current time to client, and have the client send it back, then just find difference and divide by 2 (assuming symmetrical connection).

Comment: That would only work for localhost, or same timezone though wouldn't it? This will have multiple connections, hopefully from different countries.

Comment: The client's time doesn't come into it. Say it is 9:30:00 on the server and 5:30 on the client. The server sends the client a packet with "9:30:00" in it, the client sends it back, the server receives it. It's now 9:30:01 on the server, so the server can deduce that it took 1 second roundtrip, or 0.5 sec each way... You could achieve the same by storing the time in the server state for each packet it sent, but this way is simpler (and dirtier).

Answer (score 3):

It is very difficult to get the unidirectional latency (server→client) of a connection. You can do it if you know that you have very accurate time on each end of the connection (e.g. GPS or atomic clock or high quality NTP-synced clock very close to that) and software running on each side dedicated to the task.

Otherwise, the best you can do is calculate the latency in both directions (RTT, round trip time), divide by 2, and hope the connection is path of the packets is symmetrical. If the path of the packets is not symmetrical then packets take longer to travel in one direction than the other and you cannot know a priori how much longer.

Calculating RTT is trivial: have the first side send out a short message and have the other end immediately return another one. The first side subtracts the time the response message was received from the time the request message was sent to get the RTT.